# Rspec, stub method and return a prefined value

Tags: mocking, rspec

I want to test this destroy action:

```
  def destroy
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
   @comment_id = @comment.id
   if @comment.delete_permission(current_user.id)
     @remove_comment = true
     @comment.destroy
   else
     @remove_comment = false
     head :forbidden
   end
 end
```

My spec is this:

```
    describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do
      describe 'via ajx' do
        it "should be successful if permission true" do
          comment = Comment.stub(:find).with(37).and_return @comment
          comment.should_receive(:delete_permission).with(@user.id).and_return true
          comment.should_receive(:destroy)

          delete 'destroy', :id => 37
        end
      end
    end
```

I always get:

```
comment.should_receive....
expected: 1 time
received: 0 times
```

Why :delete_permission is never called? Do you have any suggestion on how to test it?

Comment: I thought that comment = Comment.stub(:find).with(37).and_return @comment was going to assign @comment to comment. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're telling `Comment.find` to return `@comment`, but you never set the `delete_permission` expectation on that object; you set it on the value returned by the `stub` call, the `comment` local variable.

Try this:

```
# As Jimmy Cuadra notes, we have no idea what you've assigned to @comment
# But if you're not doing anything super weird, this should work
@comment.should_receive(:delete_permission).with(@user.id).and_return(true)
@comment.should_receive(:destroy)

Comment.stub(:find).with(37).and_return(@comment)
```